# Using Heredoc with command substitution referring to the shell PID differs between ksh and bash

Tags: bash, shell-script, ksh

Korn script:

```
#!/bin/ksh
sqlplus -s / << EOF
define a=$(pgrep -P $$)
define a
!ptree &a
EOF
```

VS

Bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
sqlplus -s / << EOF
define a=$(pgrep -P $$)
define a
!ptree &a
EOF
```

Korn shell output (doesn't work as expected):

```
$ /tmp/testsql.ksh
SP2-0137: DEFINE requires a value following equal sign
SP2-0135: symbol a is UNDEFINED
Enter value for a:
SP2-0546: User requested Interrupt or EOF detected.
```

Bash shell output (works as expected):

```
$ /tmp/testsql.bash
DEFINE A               = "2713" (CHAR)
  710 /usr/lib/ssh/sshd
   9574 /usr/lib/ssh/sshd -R
     9578 /usr/lib/ssh/sshd -R
.
.
.
                     2712 /bin/bash /tmp/testsql.sh
                       2713 sqlplus -s /
                         2717 ptree 2713
```

Any ideas how to make this work in ksh script?

Comment: define is sqlplus command to define a variable. Nothing to do with alias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change it to:

```
(cat; exec ps -o pid,args) << EOF
$(ps -o pid,ppid,args -H)
EOF
```

To see what's going on.

With `bash`, you'll see:

```
$ bash ./script
    PID    PPID COMMAND
 428458  428451 /bin/zsh
 976353  428458   bash ./script
 976354  976353     bash ./script
 976355  976354       ps -o pid,ppid,args -H
    PID COMMAND
 428458 /bin/zsh
 976353 bash ./script
 976354 ps -o pid,args
```

```
$ ksh93u+m ./script
    PID    PPID COMMAND
 428458  428451 /bin/zsh
 976559  428458   ksh93u+m ./script
 976560  976559     ps -o pid,ppid,args -H
    PID COMMAND
 428458 /bin/zsh
 976559 ksh93u+m ./script
 976562 ps -o pid,args
```

See how in `bash`, 976354 (a child of `$$`) is the one that forked a child process to run the command-substituted `ps`, and later went on to execute `ps`, while in ksh, the process that ran the command-substituted `ps` was forked by the main ksh process (`$$`), so earlier.

`pgrep -P "$$"` lists the child processes of the process that executed the shell to interpret your script (but never lists itself). In bash, that happens to include the process that will eventually run your `sqlplus` because `bash` so happens to do it that way.

Doing it that way makes job control in interactive shells easier, as you can put the command-substituted process in the foreground process group, so it's interrupted as well when you press Ctrl+C, and you'll find that ksh93, when running interactively does it as well when the redirected command is an external command.

But in the case of ksh, at the time `pgrep -P` is running, there's not other child of `$$` than the one that is running `pgrep` itself. The one that will run `sqlplus` will be started later, so `pgrep`'s output will be empty, and your `sqlplus` complains about that `define=`.

If the point is to have `define=<pid>` fed to `sqlplus` where `<pid>` is the pid of the process that will execute `sqlplus`, a more reliable way would be with:

```
sh -c 'exec sqlplus -s / << EOF
define a=$$
define a
!ptree &a
EOF'
```

Where, because we use `exec`, we know the `$$` in that new `sh` instance is the process that will execute `sqlplus`.

Comment: Thanks Stephane,
I knew that ksh was doing command substitution expansion $() even before running sqlplus hence the child process returning null value.
Your explanation was spot on, exec works like a charm in this case.